# Interpreting the space $\mathcal{M}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ with a weak topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

In a certain paper, the authors introduce the space of locally finite measures $\mathcal{M}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ with the topology generated by the natural bilinear form on $\mathcal{M}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}) \times C_{c}(\mathbb{R}) =: Y \times Z$.

I wish to understand what this really means. I understand the meaning of the space $\mathcal{M}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$, but what confuses me is when we put this 'topology' on it. What does that really mean? Is the norm on the space now different or something? And is there a notion of weak convergence in this space now or does that not make any sense?

Here are some of my thoughts:

The natural bilinear form on $Y \times Z$ would be

$$ a(\mu, f) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f~d\mu. $$ One way I can think of interpreting the phrase 'topology generated by this bilinear form' is as follows: we say that $\mu_{n} \to \mu$ in $Y$ under this topology if $a(\mu_{n}, f) \to a(\mu, f)$ for any $f \in Z$. And from that I guess you can build a topology (i.e. characterise open sets)?

My thoughts are probably a bit muddled but in short i want to understand how to characterise convergence in this space.

Comment: Your thoughts go in the right direction. The *weak topology* on $\mathcal M_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ is in fact the finest topology such that the functions $\mu\mapsto \alpha(\mu,f)$ are continuous. A set $M$ is open if and only if, for each $\mu\in M$, there are $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $$\bigcap_{k=1}^n\{v: |\alpha(\nu-\mu,f_k)|<\varepsilon\} \subseteq M.$$